In monaco editor tokenizer, is there a way to make a rule always take effect, and other rule take effect based on it?
Encountered such a requirement, for the entire editor, only columns 0~71 can be used. If the following columns (72~) have content, then these contents should be marked as comments. And if a comma appears in columns 0 to 71, the comma and the content after it are comments.
I wrote the following tokenizer:

return {
  tokenizer: {
    root: [
      [/(,\s+)(.*)/, ['default', 'comment']],
      [/^(.{0,71})(.*)/, ['default', 'comment']]
    ],
  },
};


I want to regard the second rule as a "global rule", which will always take effect, and then other rules can also take effect. But I found that the first rule never takes effect, and the second rule always takes effect.
Tried to put [/,\s+/, { token: 'default', next: '@comment'}], on the first line. If you enter ddd, ,this rule will not be matched. It directly matches the second rule.
I don’t know where the error occurred, or whether there is any configuration in the Monaco editor that can meet the above requirements?

Maybe you should change your mind. You should put the rule that match comment first and let them match first.
Here's an example of what you need: playground
// Register a new language
monaco.languages.register({ id: "mySpecialLanguage" });

// Register a tokens provider for the language
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider("mySpecialLanguage", {
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/^.{72,}$/, "comment"],
            [/(.*)(,\s+)(.*)/, ['default','default', 'comment']],
        ],
    },
});

monaco.editor.defineTheme("myCoolTheme", {
    base: "vs",
    inherit: false,
    rules: [
        { token: "comment", foreground: "ff0000", fontStyle: "bold" },
    ],
    colors: {
        "editor.foreground": "#000000",
    },
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    theme: "myCoolTheme",
    value: getCode(),
    language: "mySpecialLanguage",
});

function getCode() {
    return [
        "This is comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "normal line",
        "normal line with comment, 123",
    ].join("\n");
}


Thanks for your help LIQI. I want to mark the 0~71 columns as default, 72 ~ end line as comment.
here is the playground that I have tried.
The "should be marked as comments" in forth line should be comments, but it havn't been marked as comment. How can I modify the rules to achieve this? Thanks
